# NGRX Feature state (slice) in standalone components without providers in route config

Tags: ngrx, angular-state-managmement, angular-standalone-components

Need help, is there any way to create feature slices for ngrx state without putting in route block for standalone components. previously we have  NgModule approach to achieve the same.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forFeature('someFeatureName', reducerFunction),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([SomeFeatureEffect])
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  exports: []
})
export class SomeFeatureModule { }
```

But now there is no NgModule. can we achieve the same thing by another way, without putting them in route config.